# Google Sheet Returned values from query into a drop down

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

so basically if i were to make a simple query, that pulls a few data. it would just paste the value in individual cell. Would it be possible for those return values be automatically made into a drop down?

Answer (score 1):

Right click a cell that you would want the dropdown to exist in, select data validation. Then, use the "List from range" criteria and select the cells that your query result would display in.

[image]

[image]